# how to use Thread extension for Tcl using Cygwin

Tags: multithreading, package, cygwin, tcl, expect

is Thread package available on the Cygwin installer? what name does it has? (for example I am using expect in tcl without problems and I just downloaded the package 'expect' on the cygwin installer). If it does not exist on the cygwin installer, how can I install it manually?

I want to successfully test the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
package require Tcl 8.6
package require Thread
log_user 0
fconfigure stdout -buffersize 10000
set timeout 20
puts "*** I'm thread [thread::id]"
# Create 3 threads
for {set thread 1} {$thread <= 3} {incr thread} {
set id [thread::create {
# Print a hello message 3 times, waiting
# a random amount of time between messages
for {set i 1} {$i <= 3} {incr i} {
after [expr { int(500*rand()) }]
puts "Thread [thread::id] says hello"
}
}] ;# thread::create
puts "*** Started thread $id"
} ;# for
puts "*** Existing threads: [thread::names]"
# Wait until all other threads are finished
while {[llength [thread::names]] > 1} {
after 500
}
puts "*** That's all, folks!"
exit 0
```

when I run this code it gives me the following output:

```
    bender@computer /cygdrive/c/Users/bender/Documents/TCL SCRIPTS
$ ./thread.tcl
can't find package Thread
    while executing
"package require Thread"
    (file "./thread.tcl" line 3)
```

any help will be kindly appreciated

Just a comment: For network scripts I prefer Tcl Expect than c#, because Tcl is easy to implement and it does not require compilation, and I think Python is too heavy, anyway, I would like to hear any suggestion about this

Comment: What is the `Cygwin installer`? Can you post the URL where you obtained that "installer"? Also: You can reduce your script demonstrating the perceived problem to the one line `package require Thread`.

Comment: what Tcl version are you using? try a script with `puts [info patchlevel]`.

Comment: @mrcalvin probaly the Cygwin package manager from https://cygwin.com/install.html; seems like they provide `tcl-devel-8.5.18-1`, `tcl-devel-8.6.6-1`, and `tcl-devel-8.6.8-1` packages.

Comment: I wonder if Cygwin are providing non-thread-aware builds of Tcl. If so, the Thread package will refuse to be present as it cannot possibly work correctly.

Comment: So pls report the output of `puts [set tcl_platform(threaded)]`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the asker is not supplying critical details about the configuration despite having been asked to do so for several days.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn thanks for your help. The version is:
`bender@computer ~ $`
`tclsh % puts [info patchlevel]`
`8.6.8`

Comment: @mrcalvin thanks for your help. The url is http://cygwin.mirror.constant.com
and the required output is: `bender@computer ~ $`
`tclsh % puts [set tcl_platform(threaded)]`
`1`

Answer (score 0):

The situation can be confusing at first. The TCL core gets compiled with threading support as a configure option. However, in order to take advantage of threads in TCL, you would typically use the **Thread extension** or package.
**Cygwin doesn't provide this by default, but I wish it did!**

You have two choices. The first is to download and compile and install the extension in your cygwin system. I did some leg-work and I think this is the right location to get the source code from:
[Tcl Thread Extension on SF](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tcl/files/Thread%20Extension/)
Configure / install that as normal.

Another option is to use ActiveState's Tcl/Tk, which (at present) includes Thread, since it's "batteries included". You could, for example, make a symlink in your cygwin install's /usr/bin towards your Windows ActiveState tclsh.exe, which e.g. might be installed at /cygdrive/c/Tcl/bin/tclsh.exe.